# Undefined reference error after using Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I wrote a makefile to link all the .c files that i wanted to.But then again i get errors of undefined reference.The code for the makefile is:

```
FILES.o=set.o hash.o nfa.o printnfa.o input.o terp.o dfa.o minimize.o defnext.o print_ar.o pairs.o squash.o print.o assort.o prnt.o printv.o bintoasc.o ferr.o onferr.o fputstr.o pchar.o driver.o searchenv.o hashadd.o 

PROGRAM= lexer

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

But still it leads to undefined errors like :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function   `_start':(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
nfa.o: In function `parse_err':
nfa.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `Actual_lineno'
nfa.o: In function `save':
nfa.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to `Lineno'  
nfa.o: In function `advance':
nfa.c:(.text+0x8b4): undefined reference to `esc'
nfa.o: In function `rule':
nfa.c:(.text+0xae1): undefined reference to `Unix'
nfa.o: In function `term':
nfa.c:(.text+0xfbd): undefined reference to `Unix'
nfa.c:(.text+0x10a2): undefined reference to `Unix'
nfa.o: In function `thompson':
nfa.c:(.text+0x1355): undefined reference to `CLEAR_STACK'
nfa.c:(.text+0x13ab): undefined reference to `Verbose'
nfa.c:(.text+0x13d3): undefined reference to `printf_nfa'
nfa.c:(.text+0x13d9): undefined reference to `Verbose'
input.o: In function `get_expr':
input.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Input_buf'
input.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Verbose'
input.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `Actual_lineno'
input.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `Actual_lineno'
input.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `Actual_lineno'
input.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `Actual_lineno'
input.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `Input_buf'
input.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `Input_buf'
input.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `Ifile'
input.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `Verbose'
input.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `Input_buf'
input.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `Input_buf'
dfa.o: In function `dfa':
dfa.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `Verbose'
dfa.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `Verbose'
dfa.c:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `Verbose'
dfa.o: In function `get_unmarked':
dfa.c:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `Verbose'
minimize.o: In function `init_groups':
minimize.c:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `Verbose'
minimize.o:minimize.c:(.text+0x550): more undefined references to `Verbose' follow
print.o: In function `pdriver': 
print.c:(.text+0x483): undefined reference to `No_lines' 
print.c:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `No_lines'
print.c:(.text+0x4f6): undefined reference to `Input_file_name'  
print.c:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `No_lines'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lexer] Error 1
```

All the undefined references are however present in 2 header files :1.stack.h 2.global.h..Still the errors.please help!

The global.h file i am using is:

```
#ifndef __GLOBAL_H 
#define __GLOBAL_H
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef ALLOC
#   define CLASS
#   define I(x) x
#else
#   define CLASS extern
#   define I(x)
#endif
#define MAXINP 2048

CLASS int Verbose   I(=0);
CLASS int No_lines  I(=0);
CLASS int Unix      I(=0);
CLASS int Public    I(=0);
CLASS char *Template    I(="lex.par");
CLASS int Actual_lineno I(=1);
CLASS int Lineno    I(=1);

CLASS char Input_buf[MAXINP];   //line buffer for input
CLASS char *Input_file_name;    //Input file name
CLASS FILE *Ifile;      //Input Stream
CLASS FILE *ofile;      //Output Stream

#endif
```

Comment: Did you specify `CFLAGS` and other variables in the Makefile?

Comment: No.I am absolutely new to the concept of makefiles.

Comment: `1.stack.h 2.global.h.` is where in same directory? use `-I` flag to include your header files as well.

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory.use how?

Comment: Please refer to the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: What are the undefined references? They look like global variables, which you have probably only declared, not defined. (Your `stack.h` and `global.h` look like header-only includes.)

Comment: @MOehm Yes they are header includes.

Comment: @Jayesh -no it didn't work

Comment: So your problem might be is you not include header files in your source files. can you included in that?

Comment: I have included it everywhere

Comment: ok, can you show you whole makefile here? also try like `$(cc) $(CCFLAGS) ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} -o $@ $^`

Comment: Have you declared the variables as `extern`? If so, you need to provide one instance where they are really defined, otherwise the symbols are undefined.

Comment: I have included global.h in the question.

Comment: And you have `#define ALLOC` in one file before including `global.h`? You need to do that so the global variables have actual storage allocated to them. You should also do that only in one source file in oder not to get multiple references. In all inclusions without `ALLOC` the header just includes declaration, which means "There is an `int` called `Unix` somewhere but I don't care where it is - the linker should sort it out."

Comment: No i don't  have #define ALLOC in one file.

Comment: @MOehm Can you show me what i should do?I am new to this.

Comment: Then chose one of the files where you include `global.h`, define `ALLOC` before including it and try again. (Alternatively, you could create a `global.c` where you do that. You'll need to add `global.o` to your object list in the Makefile, of course.)

Comment: I include global in almost all the files.So it has to defined individually and also i must have a global.c just initialising those?

Comment: No. You just need to have one file (or better: compilation unit) where you actually define the variabes in `global.h`. The way `global.h` is written, that is controlled by defining `ALLOC`. Pick one file and `#define ALLOC` before including `global.h`. (Forget about `global.c` for now. It was a suggestion, but I've added more confusion. Sorry for that.)

Comment: @Paku So have you defined all functions in `.c` files? like you must have dafination off all function in probably `global.c` and `stack.c` files

Comment: @MOehmSo just #define ALLOC in any one of the files that include global.h will do the trick? Or should i define it in all the files including it?

Comment: @Jayesh- No i don't have a stack.h or global.h.but stack.h doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: @Paku: No, just in one file. Otherwise, you'll get "multiple references" errors on linking, because you have defined the same symbol in various object files. Pick one file and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to the Makefile per se. The header-only include file `global.h` contains declarations of variables. These declarations have to be turned into actual definitions in one compilation unit, so that they have space for them allocated in one of your object files.

The way your header file is designed, the definition of the variable `ALLOC` determines whether the variables are just declared or defined.

The regular include without `ALLOC` yields for example:

```
extern int Verbose;
```

The `extern` keyword indicates that the variable `Verbose` is not defined. No memory is allocated for it (and it therefore can't have an initialiser) and that it is probably defined in another object file.

When `ALLOC` is defined, the declaration becomes a definition with initialisation:

```
int Verbose = 0;
```

Pick one of the files that include `global.h` and define `ALLOC` before including it, for example:

**input.c**

```
#define ALLOC
#include "global.h"
```

You should then have the symbol `Verbose` defined as an `int` with initial value 0 in `global.o`:

```
> nm input.o | grep Verbose
0000000000000000 B Verbose
> nm set.o | grep Verbose
                 U Verbose
```

(`nm` is a Linux utility that lists the symbols in an object file. Windows has `dumpbin`.)

The `U` in the object file without `ALLOC` means that the symbol is undefined, i.e. referenced but not defined in this object file. The `B` in `input.o` denotes the section where the symol is defined. When you link, you can have many `U`s, but for each symbol that is undefined in an object file, you also need one object file where the symbol is defined.

Comment: @Paku: Have you written a `main` routine? If so, have you included the object file in question to your list of objects in the Makefile?

Comment: Yes terp.c has main routine.And in the makefile in is terp.o

Comment: @Paku: Hmmm. Seems okay then. Let's grasp at straws: If you do `nm terp.o < grep main`, does it show `T main`? Might there be a macro that substitutes `main` for something else? Do you use fancy `CFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`? Could you remove all object files and `make` afreash?

Comment: I just showed the main in another question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611696/undefined-reference-instead-of-makefile

Comment: @Paku: I see. You've got a good answer there. (So it seems `main` wasn't compiled after all. Judging by the `CLASS` and `MAIN` macros I think your code tries to be too clever. They are nice tricks if you know them, but it's too easy to get confused and trip over them.)

Answer (score 0):

you should add header files in all files which are contained in makefile...
otherwise those files will not able to recognize those variables

Comment: does your header file contains all these header files and global var?

Comment: My header file contains the global variables

Comment: So does, say, `print.c` contain `#include`s for both your header files?

Comment: undefined reference error means that your function cant find those var. so here problem will must be for global var/header files/fun declaration

Comment: No i have linked them all together.The global.h has those variables but somehow it keeps showing the undefined reference