# Undefined reference instead of makefile

Tags: c, makefile

The code i want to run has the makefile and it shows the error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [Nfa] Error 1
```

The file with the main function is terp.c.
The part of the code with main() is:

```
#ifdef MAIN
#define ALLOCATE
#include "global.h" /*externs for Verbose*/

#define SIZE 256

PRIVATE char BUf[BSIZE] //input buffer
PRIVATE char *Pbuf=BUf; //current position in input buffer
PRIVATE char *Expr; //regular expression from command Line

...
```

Skipping some code here until main...

```
void main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
 int sstate;    //Starting NFA state
 SET *start_dfastate;//Set of starting DFA states
 SET *current;  //current DFA state
 SET *next; 
 int accept;    //current Dfa state is an accept
 int c;     //current input character 
 int anchor;

 if (argc==2)
     fprintf(stderr,"Expression is %s\n",argv[1]);
 else
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"Usage:terp pattern < input\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 //Compile the NFA create the initial state,and initialize the current state to the  start state    
Expr=argv[1];
 sstate=nfa(getline);
 next=newset();
 ADD(next,sstate);
 if (!(start_dfastate=e_closure(next,&accept,&anchor)))
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"Internal error:State machine is empty\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 current=newset();
 assign(current,start_dfastate);

 while (c=nextchar())
 {
     if (next=e_closure(move(current,c),&accept,&anchor))
     {
         if (accept)
             printbuf();
         else
         {
            delset(current);
            current=next;
            continue;
        }
    }
    delset(next);
    assign(current,start_dfastate);
}
}

 #endif
```

The makefile i am using:

```
 FILES.o=set.o hash.o printnfa.o input.o nfa.o terp.o assort.o prnt.o printv.o bintoasc.o ferr.o onferr.o fputstr.o pchar.o driver.o searchenv.o hashadd.o esc.o 

 PROGRAM= Nfa
 INC := -I./debug.h -I./global.h 

 all: ${PROGRAM}

 ${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
 ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $(INC) $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

Comment: Show how you're running the compiler. Your subject mentions Makefiles but you don't actually say anything about a Makefile or post any rules in the question body.

Comment: Note that `void main()` is only legitimate on Windows. According to the standard and on all Unix-based systems, the correct return type for `main()` is `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your first line is:

```
#ifdef MAIN
```

I would say you need to define that when compiling.
Use `-DMAIN` as a preprocessor option for `gcc` in the `makefile` (you can put this line below the `INC` line):

```
CFLAGS=-DMAIN
```

This way, it will be included when the compiler is actually called:

```
${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} $(INC) $^ ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
                ▲
                ║ 
                ╚═══ This will include the `MAIN` definition for compiling
```

The other option is to remove the `#ifdef MAIN` alltogether. Don't forget the remove the corresponding `#endif` from the end of the file.

Comment: In the makefile. If you don't know how, paste your makefile in the question.

Comment: Yeah added the makefile